# como saber años que trabajo un empleado

Tags: oracle-11g

Recupere los cinco primeros empleados con su
historial su trabajo y los años que trabajó

```
(tabla JOB_HISTORY del esquema HR).

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
v_nombre employees.last_name%TYPE;
cursor EMP_CURSOR is
SELECT  LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES;
BEGIN
OPEN EMP_CURSOR;
LOOP
FETCH EMP_CURSOR INTO  v_nombre;
EXIT WHEN EMP_CURSOR%NOTFOUND OR EMP_CURSOR%ROWCOUNT > 5;
dbms_output.put_line( v_nombre);
END LOOP;
CLOSE EMP_CURSOR;
END;
```

Comment: Puedes postear la estructura de la tabla Employees?